# TFS 2010 build template xaml how to download a file from the project's sharepoint documents?

Tags: xaml, build, tfs

I made a TFS custom build definition, in which, among other things, the projects sources are zipped in a delivery directory.

I'd also like to download the latest version of the documentation from the TFS project sharepoint documents collection.

As the DownloadFile seems to be version control centric, I tried to use an InvokeProcess activity, coupled with a wget call, but I'm facing authentication issues.

Am I missing a dedicated activity which may solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving access to the Sharepoint website to the account running the build service, and putting this account credential in the wget script.

Not a very good  solution, but a working one nevertheless.